# Why this macro does not run

Tags: c, macros

```
#include<stdio.h>

#define A 11

int main() {
   int x=A
  printf(x);
}
```

I could not run this code. I think there is a problem in this macro describing. If you help me i will be so content.

Comment: Why you can't run this code? Also your printf is wrong.

Comment: Missing semicolon.

Comment: Which side is it wrong?

Comment: What do you mean by "side"?

Comment: Please study the concept of a [mcve].  Please verify your code by compiling it with strict warnings, e.g. with at least `gcc -Wall`. The code you have shown cannot have been compiled without warnings. If there are warnings and very likely compiler errors, then please quote them completly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define A 11

int main() {
   int x(A);
   // int x = A; in C

   printf("%d\n", x);
}
```

Comment: Why when you put %d it was solved?

Comment: @leurami you can search for the specifications of the printf function online.  The first parameter is a format C string

Comment: Why so does not first parameter convert into string automatically, when i put number there?

Comment: @leurami What you need is reading some actual explanations of what you try to use. Find a book and a tutorial. Start with playing with a HelloWorld. For programming, some understanding is needed on top of writing lines which look vaguels similar to other programs you have seen elsewhere. Stop guessing around, start with some systematical learning.

Comment: @AbdulAhad This is what you get for code-only answers to questions with code which looks like it cannot ever have been compiled.

Comment: @Yunnosch the end state is getting the author of the original post to be able to "read code" and search the internet for the specifications of a standard function. I don't follow the advice of fools

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by "end state". I agree with you that advising posters to read documentation is appropriate. I do not see that you do that. I do not see how giving working code without explanation helps posters to learn reading code.

Comment: Just to make sure that I do not misunderstand your intentions: You chose that obviously derogative term to refer to me personally? Is the intention of that to insult me or to participate in an appropriate, matter-of-fact technical and didactical discussion? In case you attempted the latter, I think we can agree that you are somewhat off the mark, can't we?

Comment: @Yunnosch "that's what you get", bother someone who doesn't regularly contribute more to the economy in an hour that you will in your entire life.  I still haven't gotten the critic badge.  I don't care what you think and I have no interest in interacting with you ever again.  Simply go away.